# jQuery XML Parsing/Traversing

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, traversal

I have the following XML-

```
<rows>
   <row id="5">
      <cell>Item1</cell>
   <attrs>
    <attr>
      <id>1</id>
      <type>CheckBox</type>
      <values>
        <value>
          <id>10</id>
        </value>
        <value>
          <id>11</id>
        </value>
      </values>
    </attr>
     <attr>
       <id>2</id>
       <type>CheckBox</type>
       <values>
         <value>
           <id>20</id>
         </value>
         <value>
           <id>21</id>
         </value>
       </values>
     </attr>
  </attrs>
   </row>
</rows>
```

What I want to do is to loop each of the  of a certain row.

I tried to do this in order to get all of the attr ids but I also got the values ids.

```
function fillForm(id){
    var theRow = $(theXmlDoc).find('row[id='+id+']').get()

    $(theRow).find("attr").each(function(i) 
    {
        alert($(this).find("id").text());
    });
}
```

I also would like to note that main goal is loop each attr and afterwards to loop each value while I have the attr's id.

P.S if you think of an easier/simpler way to do so with some other library I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Was just having nearly this exact same issue. +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not clear what you're trying to loop over, I think one of the tags in your question was garbled. You say: "What I want to do is to loop each of the of a certain row." and I think you had a tag in there.

Anyway, here's some examples of extracting data from the parsed xml document using jQuery. The comments show what will be alerted.

I think part of the problem is you have the id values as siblings rather than children to the attributes. It seems like a more coherent structure might be:

```
<rows>
    <row id="5">
        <cell>Item1</cell>
        <attrs>
            <attr id="1">
                <type>CheckBox</type>
                <values>
                    <value>
                        <id>10</id>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <id>11</id>
                    </value>
                </values>
            </attr>
            <attr id="2">
                <type>CheckBox</type>
                <values>
                    <value>
                        <id>20</id>
                    </value>
                    <value>
                        <id>21</id>
                    </value>
                </values>
            </attr>
        </attrs>
    </row>
</rows>
```

But if you don't have control over the xml, please ignore that suggestion. :-)

Okay, here are some samples of traversal to get various pieces of data:

First let's just get "Item1"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Item1
$.get('sample.xml', null, function (data, textStatus) {
    alert( $(data).find('rows row[id=5] cell').text());
}, 'xml');
</script>
```

Now we'll get the 1 and the 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// 1
// 2
$.get('sample.xml', null, function (data, textStatus) {
    $(data).find('rows row[id=5] attrs attr > id').each( function(){
            alert($(this).text()); // 1, 2
    });
}, 'xml');
</script>
```

And lastly, let's pull out the main attr ids and tie them into the values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// rows row[id=5] attrs attr > id 1 has inner ids of 10,11
// rows row[id=5] attrs attr > id 2 has inner ids of 20,21
$.get('sample.xml', null, function (data, textStatus) {

        var out = ''
        $(data).find('rows row[id=5] attrs attr > id').each( function(){
                out += 'rows row[id=5] attrs attr > id ' + $(this).text();
                var innerIds = [];
                $(this).siblings('values').find('value id').each(function(){
                    innerIds.push($(this).text())
                });
                out += ' has inner Ids of ' + innerIds.join(',') + '\n';
        });
        alert(out);
    }, 'xml');
</script>
```

Comment: Basically what I want to loop over is the attrs, and for each attr I need to fetch each of his values, and in addition to fetch attr's id, I can't change the xml so I need a solution for that.

I'll try your code tomorrow when I'll have my workstation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
function fillForm(id){
    var row = $(theXmlDoc).find('row#+'+ id);
    var ids = row.find( "attr > id");

    ids.each(function(i) 
    {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
}
```

PS. You can use [xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) either:

```
var ids = document.evaluate( '//rows/row[@id='+id + ']/attr/id/text( )', theXmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Comment: Edited. Sorry, I can't test it here.